# Calculating python variable only once

Tags: python, variables, memory, import

I want to extract an excel file in my script extractor.py and import it my script calculation.py but without recalculating it!

Here is my code :

in extractor.py

```
current_directory=os.getcwd()
workbook_clients=pandas.ExcelFile(current_directory+"/Documents/clients.xlsx")      
clients=pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile.parse(workbook_clients)
```

in calculation.py

```
from extractor import * 
print clients
```

Right now when I run calculation.py it takes 30 seconds to run and I don't understand why, I just want to call a variable in memory...

Comment: How big is your excel file?  Is what you've shown everything that's in extractor.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your dataset is very large, `read_csv` should be a lot faster than `read_excel`. [(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182822/csv-xlsx-files-import-to-pandas-data-frame-speed-issue)

Edit after your comments: write a method if you want to make sure that you are getting the values with the extractor just once in your routine

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def get_data():
    current_directory=os.getcwd()
    workbook_clients=pd.ExcelFile(current_directory+"/Documents/clients.xlsx")      
    data=pd.io.excel.ExcelFile.parse(workbook_clients)
    return data

clients = get_data()
print(clients)
```

Now you can do with `clients` whatever you want and it's being called from memory. In case you want to re-read the data, just call the method again.

Obviously, you can also write the method inside the extractor.py and call it from somewhere else.

BTW: `from module import *` is on the *you should not do*-list. [Further reading.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/doanddont.html) :)

Comment: There is nothing else in extractor.py... for example when I comment out the  "from extractor import * ", I get an instant answer because python is looking for the "clients" variable in memory ... But It feels like this commenting/uncommenting solution is not the best one. I tried read_csv and it is a bit faster but the matter here is really just to read the excel file once and then reuse the variable

Comment: Okay, but reading the data from memory is not what you want, I assume. Is converting the xlsx to csv a possibility for you? You can do it in Excel via `save as`...

How big is your dataset?

Comment: Thank you Klaster ! To be more precise I want to be able to decide to read the data from memory or not ... Escuse me if I am not clear. I know there is a way to optimize the dataset reading by converting formats, but it is not what i'm looking for here. For example in Excel, one can decide wether to copy/paste a formula or just a value of a cell. Here I want to understand when my variable is reevaluated or just called in memory

Comment: Thank you Klaster !! I'll vote your answer up as soon as I have enough reputation ( In a long time apparently ...)

Comment: For now, you can simply mark it as solved (green tick on the left). ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally found another way to do what I want :

in extractor.py

```
current_directory=os.getcwd()
workbook_clients=pandas.ExcelFile(current_directory+"/Documents/clients.xlsx")
global clients 
clients=pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile.parse(workbook_clients)
```

in calculation.py

```
print clients
```