# Loading only one sheet to dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

I am trying to read an excel sheet into df using pandas read_excel method. The excel file contains 6-7 different sheet. Out of it, 2-3 sheets are very huge. I only want to read one excel sheet out of the file. 
If I copy the sheet out and read the time reduces by 90%.

I have read that xlrd that is used by pandas always loads the whole sheet to memory. I cannot change the format of the input.

Can you please suggest a way to improve the performance?

Comment: What about `xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')` and `df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet1')`

Comment: This is what we are using currently. It loads all the sheet it seems. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook) StackOverflow question is the closest related to above question I came across. But it doesn't solve the problem I guess

Comment: What's wrong with `data_file = pd.read_excel('path_to_file.xls', sheetname="Sheet1")`?

Comment: see this question and adapt the answer to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766133/faster-way-to-read-excel-files-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple.  Just do this.

```
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile('C:/users/path_to_your_excel_file/Analysis.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1')
print(df1)
# etc.
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet2')
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('YourFile.xlsx', sheet_name = 'YourSheet_Name')
```

Whatever sheet you want to read just put the sheet name and your path to excel file.

Answer (score -1):

Use openpyxl in read-only mode. See http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/pandas.html