# How to increase process speed using read_excel in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, performance, dataframe

I need use *pd.read_excel* to process every sheet in one excel file.
But in most cases,I did not know the sheet name.
So I use this to judge how many sheet in excel:

```
i_sheet_count=0
i=0
try:
  df.read_excel('/tmp/1.xlsx',sheetname=i)
  i_sheet_count+=1
  i+=1
else:
  i+=1
print(i_sheet_count)
```

During the process,I found  that the process is quite slow,
So,can *read_excel* only read limited rows to improve the speed?
I tried *nrows* but did not work..still slow..

Comment: So what is you problem? Find all the sheet_names or read limit rows?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Read all worksheets without guessing

Use `sheet_name = None` argument to `pd.read_excel`. This will read *all* worksheets into a dictionary of dataframes. For example:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

# access 'Sheet1' worksheet
res = dfs['Sheet1']
```

#### Limit number of rows or columns

You can use `parse_cols` and `skip_footer` arguments to limit the number of columns and/or rows. This will reduce read time, and also works with `sheet_name = None`.

For example, the following will read the first 3 columns and, if your worksheet has 100 rows, it will read only the first 20.

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None, usecols='A:C', skip_footer=80)
```

If you wish to apply worksheet-specific logic, you can do so by extracting sheet_names:

```
sheet_names = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx', on_demand=True).sheet_names

dfs = {}
for sheet in sheet_names:
    dfs[sheet] = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet)
```

#### Improving performance

Reading Excel files into Pandas is naturally slower than other options (CSV, Pickle, HDF5). If you wish to improve performance, I strongly suggest you consider these other formats.

One option, for example, is to [use a VBA script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28769537/9209546) to convert your Excel worksheets to CSV files; then use `pd.read_csv`.

Edit 02 Nov: correct `sheetname` to `sheet_name`

Comment: for new version replace 'parse_cols' with 'usecols'
document: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: `skip_footer` should be `skipfooter`

Comment: Also, does using `usecols` and `skipfooter` actually increase loading speed? For a file I'm testing it on there's no discernible speed boost

Answer (score 0):

I had excel with many sheets. I wanted only those sheets whose state is visible. If you do not know about that its fine. But if you want to read your sheet names from excel then you can use this code. it took me average 3 sec time to read near about 20 sheet names. It takes quite a few attempts to get this.

```
file_name = r'C:\Users\xyz.xlsx'
File_sheet_list = []
workbookObj = pd.ExcelFile(file_name)
LenOfWorkBook = len(workbookObj.book.worksheets)
idx = 0
for idx in range(0, LenOfWorkBook ):
  if workbookObj.book.worksheets[idx].sheet_state == "visible":
    File_sheet_list.append(workbookObj.book.worksheets[idx].title)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using `nrows`

You can use `nrows` to read sheet names more quickly than would otherwise be possible.

```py
def read_sheet_names(file_name):
    sheet_list = list(pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=None, nrows=0).keys())
    return sheet_list

file_name= 'foo.xlsx'
read_sheet_names(file_name)
```

(This also uses `sheet_name=None` as noted in @jpp's answer.)

Then once you've found the names of the sheets:

```py
pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='bar')
```

### Benchmarking

Results for an 8MB XLSX file with nine sheets, where one of the sheets, `baz` contains lots more data than the other sheets.

Reading one of the shorter sheets, `bar` - note the huge speed gain:

```py
%timeit pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=read_sheet_names(file_path)[0])
>>> 143 ms ± 9.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=None)['bar']
>>> 22 s ± 5.89 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

There isn't really any speed improvement if trying to read in `baz`, the long, ninth sheet:

```py
%timeit pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=read_sheet_names(file_path)[-1])
>>> 17.6 s ± 5.23 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=None)['baz']
>>> 17.5 s ± 3.29 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can install Libreoffice in your environment. You can use it to convert Excel files to CSV in Python and use read_csv instead of read_excel.

The sample code is below:

```
def convert_excel_to_csv(input_file):
    exe_path = 'C:/Program Files/LibreOffice/program/soffice.exe'
    
    command = [
        exe_path,
        '--headless',
        '--convert-to', 'csv',
        '--outdir', os.path.dirname(__file__),
        input_file
    ]
    subprocess.run(command, check=True)
```