# Is there a preferred format for Python to retrieve time-series data - between .txt or xlsx?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, text

I am using a third party tool to extract vast amounts of time-series data (to be analysed within python). The options are to save this as a text file or excel file. Which is the more efficient route speed-wise?

Comment: Save files in .csv format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look here: [Faster way to read Excel files to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766133/faster-way-to-read-excel-files-to-pandas-dataframe)

Here it is also mentioned that csv is fater, so the text file should be the better option.