# Optimizing processing of a large excel file

Tags: python, dask, phone-number

I am working on a large dataset where I need to read excel files and then find valid numbers but the task takes enormous time for only 500k data. For valid numbers, I am using google phonelib. processing can be done in an async way as they are independent.

```py
parts = dask.delayed(pd.read_excel)('500k.xlsx')
data = dd.from_delayed(parts)
data['Valid'] = data['Mobile'].apply(lambda x: phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phonenumbers.parse(x)),meta=('Valid','object'))
```

for background

```py
phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phonenumbers.parse('+442083661177'))
```

gives output as True

I expect the output to be less than 10sec but it takes around 40s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Faster way to read Excel files to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766133/faster-way-to-read-excel-files-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @emilanov Reading a Dataframe is not the only concern I also want to process the dataframe in a parallel manner

Comment: I'm not sure how many people know "lac" as a suffix, writing it as 500k might make it more accessible

Comment: Okay! @SamMason  I have edited the code

Comment: I didn't notice it in the code, I was meaning in the description at the top :)

Comment: depending on whether `phonelib` [releases the GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1294382/1358308) you might be better off with a different dask scheduler https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling.html using something other than threads would bypass the GIL and might help

Comment: @SamMason I tried but still the speed is slow can you try working on it ! populate a csv file with same number and then make it huge and please can you tell me if you can make it fast

Comment: it takes my computer approx 100ms to run your parse and validate code 1000 times, which would imply 500k items would take at least 50 seconds.  this is pretty similar to your 40seconds, and makes me wonder if you're getting any parallelism out of dask at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just been playing with this and you might just need to [`repartition` your dataframe](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.repartition) to allow the computation to be run in parallel

I start by generating some data:

```
import csv
import random
with open('tmp.csv', 'w') as fd:
    out = csv.writer(fd)
    out.writerow(['id', 'number'])
    for i in range(500_000):
        a = random.randrange(1000, 2999)
        b = random.randrange(100_000, 899_999)
        out.writerow([i+1, f'+44 {a} {b}'])
```

note that these are mostly valid UK numbers.

I then run something similar to your code:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as dd
import phonenumbers

def fn(num):
    return phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phonenumbers.parse(num))

with Client(processes=True):
    df = dd.read_csv('tmp.csv')

    # repartition to increase parallelism
    df = df.repartition(npartitions=8)

    df['valid'] = df.number.apply(fn, meta=('valid', 'object'))

    out = df.compute()
```

this takes ~20 seconds to complete on my laptop (4 cores, 8 threads, Linux 5.2.8), which is only a bit more than double the performance of the plain loop.  which indicates dask has quite a bit of runtime overhead as I'd expect it to be much faster than that.  if I remove the call to `repartition` it takes a longer than I'm willing to wait and `top` only shows a single process running

note that if I rewrite it to do the naive thing in `multiprocessing` I get much better results:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv')

with Pool(4) as pool:
    df['valid'] = pool.map(fn, df['number'])
```

which reduces runtime to ~11 seconds and is even less code here as a bonus

Comment: Reading csv is fast @SamMason any way to speed up reading excel files also ?

Comment: note: I'm strongly biased against anything microsoft...  why not just convert to CSV as soon as possible and "archive" the excel files, they're generally not very useful for anything apart from sharing with non-computer-literate people

Comment: Well that is the task since excel is cumbersome I am supposed to convert it to CSV but it takes more time than expected @SamMason so maybe if you could help me optimize it would be great. Currently reading csv from pandas take around 30s for 10L rows

Comment: is "10L rows" 1 million (i.e. 1e6) rows?  people outside india don't really use lakh, you're better off sticking to [SI prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) on stackoverflow...  reading a 1M row CSV file in pandas on my laptop takes approx 25ms per numeric column and 100ms per text column, i.e. 0.3 seconds for 4 numeric and 2 text columns.  there are lots of articles about optimising Python/numeric code, if you can't find anything maybe post another question here or on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you're CSV file contatins +99001166773

Comment: The whole system gets hang

Comment: I get a valid exception parsing that.  maybe find some tutorials on exception handling in Python, or post another question...