# How to read large xlsx file to fast in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsx, large-files

Is there any option to read and get DataFrame in **fast** with *large excel* files in python?

Comment: If it is a single sheet, save it as .csv and use pd.read_csv(). If it is multi sheet try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766133/faster-way-to-read-excel-files-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Pandas provides a function to read excel files:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

I think you need to install `xlrd` separately for this

```
pip install xlrd
```

Please mention in your question if you already know about this and looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: I kow this ,but what I am asking, how to large xlsx file to get dataframe in fast?