# How to read a created list of .xlsx files into a concatenated pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to Python so bear with me. I have a list of 30+ .xlsx files that I want to be read into a list of data frames. After that, I want them to be concatenated into a single data frame.

I have a function that creates a list of .xlsx files from a given directory:

```
from os import listdir

working_directory = 'N:/path to files'

def find_xlsx_filenames(path_to_dir, suffix=".xlsx"):
        """
        The function find_xlsx_filenames() returns a list of filenames as strings, that reside in the directory path_to_dir with the 
        given suffix (by default,".xlsx").
        """
        filenames = listdir(path_to_dir)
        return[filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(suffix)]
    
# Creates a list of all validation xlsx files in the folder:
filenames = find_xlsx_filenames(working_directory) 
for file_list in filenames:
    print(file_list)
```

And this is what the output looks like:

[image]

I want to take this list of files and apply a function that reads them into separate data frames, then combines them into a single data frame. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all parameters you need to `pd.read_excel`:

```
import glob
import os

data = [pd.read_excel(filename)
            for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(working_directory, "*.xlsx")]
df = pd.concat(data).reset_index(drop=True)
```

If your files are large, I have a `multiprocessing` version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67734402/15239951)

**Edit**: *implement the code by defining a function?*

In this version, I do not use `glob` anymore. You are responsible to set the `file_path` directory and the list of `filenames` returned by your function `find_xlsx_filenames`.

```
import os

def excel_to_df(file_path, filenames):
    data = [pd.read_excel(os.path.join(file_path, filename))
                for filename in filenames]
    return pd.concat(data).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to implement the code by defining a function? ex) `def excel_to_df(arguments)

Comment: Yes you can. `arguments` is a list of filenames, the working directory or other?

Comment: Up. I can do that if you answer to my question. What are `arguments`?

Comment: The `arguments` that I'd want to include are: a list of files, the file path. If you have any suggestions for any additional arguments, feel free to add them. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you