# How to use python-multiprocessing to concat many files/dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm relatively new to python and programming and just use it for the analysis of simulation data.
I have a directory "result_1/" with over 150000 CSV files with simulation data I want to concat into one pandas-dataFrame. To evade problems with readdir() only reading 32K of directory entries at a time, I prepared "files.csv" - listing all the files in the directory.

("sim", "det", and "run" are pieces of information I read from the filenames and insert as Series into the dataFrame. For better overlook, I took their definition out of the concat.)

My problem is as follows:
The program takes too much time to run and I would like to use multiprocessing/-threading to speed up the for-loop, but as I never used mp/mt before, I don't even know if or how it may be used here.

Thank you in advance and have a great day!

```
import numpy as np                          
import pandas as pd                         
import os
import multiprocessing as mp

df = pd.DataFrame()
path = 'result_1/'
list = pd.read_csv('files.csv', encoding='utf_16_le', names=['f'])['f'].values.tolist()

for file in list:
    dftemp = pd.read_csv(r'{}'.format(os.path.join(path, file)), skiprows=8, names=['x', 'y', 'z', 'dos'], sep=',').drop(['y', 'z'], axis=1)
    sim = pd.Series(int(file.split('Nr')[1].split('_')[0]) * np.ones((300,), dtype=int))
    det = pd.Series(int(file.split('Nr')[0]) * np.ones((300,), dtype=int))
    run = pd.Series(int(file[-8:-4]) * np.ones((300,), dtype=int))
    dftemp = pd.concat([sim, det, run, dftemp], axis=1)
    df = pd.concat([df, dftemp], axis=0)

df.rename({0:'sim', 1:'det', 2:'run', 3:'x', 4:'dos'}, axis=1).to_csv(r'df.csv')
```

The CSV files look like this: "193Nr6_Run_0038.csv" (f.e.)

```
#(8 lines of things I don't need.)
0, 0, 0, 4.621046656438921e-09
1, 0, 0, 4.600856584602298e-09
(... 300 lines of data [x, y, z, dose])
```

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67734402/15239951) should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing DataFrames in parallel can be difficult due to CPU and RAM limitations. I don't know the specs of your hardware nor the details of your DataFrames. However, I would use multiprocessing to "parse/make" the DataFrames, and then concatenate them afterwards. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np                          
import pandas as pd                         
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool


path = 'result_1/'
list_of_files = pd.read_csv('files.csv', encoding='utf_16_le', names=['f'])['f'].values.tolist()

#make a function to replace the for-loop:
def my_custom_func(file):
    dftemp = pd.read_csv(r'{}'.format(os.path.join(path, file)), skiprows=8, names=['x', 'y', 'z', 'dos'], sep=',').drop(['y', 'z'], axis=1)
    sim = pd.Series(int(file.split('Nr')[1].split('_')[0]) * np.ones((300,), dtype=int))
    det = pd.Series(int(file.split('Nr')[0]) * np.ones((300,), dtype=int))
    run = pd.Series(int(file[-8:-4]) * np.ones((300,), dtype=int))
    return pd.concat([sim, det, run, dftemp], axis=1)

#use multiprocessing to process multiple files at once
with Pool(8) as p: #8 processes simultaneously. Avoid using more processes than cores in your CPU
    dataframes = p.map(my_custom_func, list_of_files)

#Finally, concatenate them all
df = pd.concat(dataframes)

df.rename({0:'sim', 1:'det', 2:'run', 3:'x', 4:'dos'}, axis=1).to_csv(r'df.csv')
```

Have a look at [multiprocessing.Pool()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) for more info.

Comment: Now he tells me "name 'dataframes' is not defined"... (and loops there)