# Pandas Read Excel, or faster method

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I didn't find any related thread.

I have a not so big Excel file (100 MB), but quite large (ie 930 columns for 35k rows), and that's my problem.
Excel read this file in a second, but pandas took at least 10-20 minutes on my computer.
I tried the following:

- not infering type, by giving dtype parameter.
- limit columns, by using usecols
- iterate over rows, by using nrows and skiprows in a loop

I can not convert this excel into a csv.

This is my code so far:

```py
df = pd.read_excel("rei_2018/REI_2018.xlsx", engine = "openpyxl", dtype = str, usecols=['H11'], nrows=200)
```

**edit 1:**

- data : https://www.impots.gouv.fr/portail/www2/fichiers/statistiques/base_de_donnees/rei/rei_2018.zip
- I tried running the following command on the above data (thus limiting to 200 row), it hooks exactly 760seconds.

```py
df = pd.read_excel("rei_2018/REI_2018.xlsx", engine = "openpyxl", dtype = str, usecols=['H11'], nrows=200)
```

- pandas versions (Windows 64bits with Anaconda, on 8Gb Intel i5 8265U):

```py
pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit           : b5958ee1999e9aead1938c0bba2b674378807b3d
python           : 3.7.6.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Windows
OS-release       : 10
Version          : 10.0.18362
machine          : AMD64
processor        : Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 12, GenuineIntel
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : None
LANG             : None
LOCALE           : None.None

pandas           : 1.1.5
numpy            : 1.18.1
pytz             : 2019.3
dateutil         : 2.8.1
pip              : 20.0.2
setuptools       : 45.2.0.post20200210
Cython           : 0.29.15
pytest           : 5.3.5
hypothesis       : 5.5.4
sphinx           : 2.4.0
blosc            : None
feather          : None
xlsxwriter       : 1.2.7
lxml.etree       : 4.3.5
html5lib         : 1.0.1
pymysql          : None
psycopg2         : None
jinja2           : 2.11.1
IPython          : 7.12.0
pandas_datareader: None
bs4              : 4.8.2
bottleneck       : 1.3.2
fsspec           : 0.6.2
fastparquet      : None
gcsfs            : None
matplotlib       : 3.1.3
numexpr          : 2.7.1
odfpy            : None
openpyxl         : 3.0.3
pandas_gbq       : None
pyarrow          : 0.13.0
pytables         : None
pyxlsb           : None
s3fs             : None
scipy            : 1.4.1
sqlalchemy       : 1.3.13
tables           : 3.6.1
tabulate         : None
xarray           : None
xlrd             : 1.2.0
xlwt             : 1.3.0
numba            : 0.48.0
```

Comment: Side note: "not so big Excel file (100 MB)" - that's a *massive* Excel file (and a red flag in and of itself).

Comment: Indeed, remember [Excel is not a database](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+is+not+a+database).

Comment: Of course, I am just a user of this file, which data are OpenSourced. Thus, I can choose the file format extract of their database. My issue is not with the size, I have the same issue with 1KB Excel, with a lot of columns.

Comment: This performance is interesting. Please describe your environment (OS, virtualenv, RAM, core speed, 32-bit/64-bit, etc.). In fact, edit post with output of `pd.show_versions`. Show some sample data (or generate it for reproducibility). If many columns is an issue, this could be a ticket for [pandas team](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues).

Comment: I'm not sure you meant 1KB Excel... maybe 1MB. Either way... sounds like Excel is being (ab)used as a database.

Comment: I 100% agree with that, and I will prefer dealing with a much larger csv file. I don't understand why nowadays, this kind of data are exposed as an Excel Format.
Concerning the performance, it's kind of strange, as is a specific column is selected (use_cols), it seems that all row are still parsed, and the position in the header of the column is not use. I will try to use openpyxl only to see if I have a better performance.

Answer (score 3):

Consider an ODBC connection to Excel workbook to query worksheet like a database table with `pandas.read_sql`. Below ODBC driver installs with most Windows MS Office installations. SQL query retrieves one column, `H11`, and first 200 rows of worksheet named `mySheet`.

```py
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

strfile = "/path/to/workbook.xlsx"

conn = pyodbc.connect(
    r'Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};'
    'DBQ={};'.format(strfile), autocommit=True
)

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT TOP 200 [H11] FROM [mySheet$]", conn)

# ALTERNATIVELY, ASSUMING H11 COLUMN IS "H" COLUMN IN SPREADSHEET
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT [H11] FROM [mySheet$H1:H200]", conn)

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without converting your excel file to a csv, I think you're somewhat beat given what is said [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766133/faster-way-to-read-excel-files-to-pandas-dataframe).

That being said, it may be worth looking into [Excel VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) macros](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html). It's pretty quick to pick up and reads similarly to a python script, I had used it a few years back when I had a similar problem to you (needed to read from many excel files and couldn't use Python).